# Onclick Radio Button Disable Another Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have two groups of radio buttons. The radio buttons for `Insurance Type` and `Report Type`

code for Insurance Type:

```
<input type="radio" class="p27" name="ins_type" value="loan"/> Loan Insurance
<input type="radio" class="p27" name="ins_type" value="benefit"/> Benefit Insurance
```

and code for Report Type:

```
<input type="radio" class="p27" name="rep_type" value="normal_rep"/> Normal Listing
<input type="radio" class="p27" name="rep_type" value="loan_coverage"/> Loan Coverage
<input type="radio" class="p27" name="rep_type" value="premium_coverage"/> Premium Coverage
```

What I want to achieve is when I click the Benefit Insurance Radio Button from the Insurance Type Group, The Loan Coverage and Premium Coverage Radio Button from the Report Type Group should be disabled.

I'm not a JavaScript guy so any help would be very useful for me.

Comment: Are you supposed to have slashes at the end of those tags?

Comment: @BraydonKains I guess so, it doesnt give any errors anyway

Comment: Yes, there should be slashes at the end of them. However, most browsers won't complain if there aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, add ids for the inputs for Benefit, loan coverage, and premium coverage (say benefit, loan and premium for my code). Then use the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById('benefit').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('loan').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('premium').disabled = true;
}
```

If you want to re-enable them when they click back on loan in the insurancetype you will need another handler for that input:

```
document.getElementById('loanType').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('loan').disabled = false;
    document.getElementsById('premium').disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: But what happens if the `benefit` DOM element is clicked more than once?

Comment: It will simply set the loan and premium to disabled again, which won't do anything if they are already disabled.

Comment: Right... but what happens if `loan` is clicked afterwards?

Comment: I addressed that in my edit

Answer (score 1):

The following is a pure Javascript way to accomplish this. Really, what you need is the handle *two* events – one if the `benefit` DOM element is checked, and one if the `load` DOM element is checked. Since clicking on `load` should presumably re-enable the two disabled radio buttons, create a separate function for handling each:

```
document.getElementById('benefit') = function() {
    document.getElementById('loan_coverage').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('premium_coverage').disabled = true;
};

document.getElementById('loan') = function() {
    document.getElementById('loan_coverage').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('premium_coverage').disabled = false;
};
```

Comment: You can't uncheck a radio button by clicking on it again (at least not by default, although you could enable such behavior with javascript).

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you can uncheck a radio button by clicking it again. I'm saying that if the other radio button is clicked, you should be able to handle that event separately/appropriately.

Comment: Right, however your original code re-enabled the button when you clicked on `benefit` twice, not when you clicked on `benefit` and then `loan`. Your current code is great though.